# Unable to instantiate activity (...) - ExpendalbleListActivity

Tags: android, exception

I guess it's some basic mistake since I'm still a rookie.

```
package pl.cashflowmanager;

//all necessary imports are here

    public class SummaryOverMonths extends ExpandableListActivity {


        private CfmDbAdapter db;
        private final Cursor monthsCountQuery = db.SQLDb.rawQuery("select * from expenses", null); //crashes here with: 12-10 12:51:15.101: E/AndroidRuntime(348): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{pl.cashflowmanager/pl.cashflowmanager.SummaryOverMonths}: java.lang.NullPointerException


    //rest code goes there
```

I commented the problem. The query is fine, the database is working. Should the cursor  go inside the method or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` because you haven't instantiated the `CfmDbAdapter` yet.  You have created a field for it, yes, but you haven't put anything in it before trying to call your query on it.
So you're asking a non-existing item to perform an action, causing the `NullPointer`.

Instantiate it first like so:

```
private CfmDbAdapter db = new CfmDbAdapter(); // Or whatever constructor it expects.
private final Cursor monthsCountQuery = db.SQLDb.rawQuery("select * from expenses", null);
```

That should do the trick.